# Updating relative links and images in wiki library

Tags: 2010, powershell

I have a wiki library which contents is automatically copied onto another site. Some of the pages in the library contain images, the links to those images are relative.

Example:

page: http://www.siteA.com/wiki/pages/home.aspx

image: /wiki/images/image.jpg

Now I have a script which exports the wiki and images libraries, and imports them on another site. But on that site, the library is placed in a different subsite:

http://www.siteB.com/subsite/wiki/pages/home.aspx

Now although the images library is in the same subsite as the wiki (like it was on siteA), the images still break. They keep on pointing to /wiki/images/image.jpg instead of /subsite.wiki/images/image.jpg.

So now I'm looking for a way to correct this, preferably in a powershell script, since the exporting / importing is done in powershell too. What's a good way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried to use url token.For e.g. {SiteUrl}. I am not sure it work in wiki page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jasper,

You could try modifying the content from each wiki page through powershell by replacing the old URL with the new one.

The following blog post can help you with it: http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/modify-a-sharepoint-2010-probably-2007-as-well-wiki-page-with-powershell/

```
$content = $wiki.data.row.ows_WikiField
$content = $content -replace "/wiki/images/", "/subsite/wiki/images/"
```

Regards,
EStruyf

Answer (score 2):

For future readers: I created a Powershell script which does the same, but without the need to use the webservices. http://blog.repsaj.nl/?p=434